# How do You make a mesh

Tags: roblox

Please i dont know how to make a mesh. Please answer.

Answer (score 1):

No longer can you upload meshes to ROBLOX. There are many scripts around ROBLOX that can convert mesh data into parts, though. One of them being stavant's [MeshLib](http://www.roblox.com/MeshLib-Tests-place?id=24953449)

Answer (score 1):

You're able to upload custom meshes to ROBLOX, but you will need to turn it into an .FBX file. The only program I can think of at the top of my head currently that can support 3D models and upload it as an .FBX file is Blender. Other than that, sorry, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Originally this was not possible, but in 2016 Roblox added the ability for users to upload their own meshes.

In Roblox Studio, click the **Import** button at the bottom of the **Game Explorer** window.

Source: https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Mesh-Parts#uploading-meshes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BuildIn Libraries (Search with toolbox in studio) to transfer .obj (3d model/wavefront) files into Roblox.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now you cannot create meshes, but there are two similar options available.

1. You can get an .obj importer script from free models.  In the script, it will tell you how to use it.
2. There is this new thing called CSG.  CSG stands for constructive solid geometry.  Basically you can make parts that are similar to meshes by add or removing spaces on the initial brick.  Two new instances were added as well: NegateOperation(A part used to 'subtract' the shape of the part from another part) and Union(A part that is created by Unioning parts[Maximum triangles ~= 3600?])